# Date compatible Function from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am trying to convert the below definition to Postgres.

Current Oracle code:

```
PROCEDURE Run_All (inDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE) IS
```

In Postgres I used different versions:

1. ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.gen_fios_xml$run_all
      (indate timestamp(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
   ```
2. ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.gen_fios_xml$run_all
      (indate timestamp without timezone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date)
   ```
3. ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.gen_fios_xml$run_all
      (indate date DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date)
   ```
4. ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.gen_fios_xml$run_all
      (indate timestamp(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp(0))
   ```

But still it's throwing an error as below:

```
ERROR:  column "timestamp" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT TIMESTAMP
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "gen_fios_xml$run_all"(date) line 13 during statement block local variable initialization
SQL state: 42703
```

What would be the right way to convert, am I missing something in Postgres? Any update is absolutely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the part of the function that you are showing, it is in line 13 of the function body in a `SELECT` statement.

Your function signatures should work, but if you need the hour-to-second part of the Oracle `DATE`, the perfect translation would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.gen_fios_xml$run_all
    (indate timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT localtimestamp(0))
```

Comment: Ok, Really appreciate your time but Still the same error,!

What can be the right signature that I can use here for running the Function Sirr.?

Comment: Thanks for your time in looking into this Laurenz,you are right, its a datatype mismatch in a variable in the source code that caused the error!